# Multiselect chosen dropdown - want to set values

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, multi-select

Please let me know how can I set the selected value in the chosen multiselect dropdownlist. I have tried everything available on net but nothing is working.

My view is

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    model => model.SelectedSkills, 
    new SelectList(
        Model.SkillList, 
        "Value", 
        "Text", 
        Model.SelectedSkills
    ), 
    new { 
        @class = "chosen", 
        id = "ddlSkill",
        name="ddlPersonSkill", 
        @tabindex = "4", 
        multiple = "true"
    }
)

@Html.HiddenFor(
    model => model.SelectedSkills, 
    new { id = "hdnPersonSkill" }
)
```

Now in page load I need to display the selected value :

```
var personskill = $("#hdnPersonSkill").val(); 
$('#ddlSkill option:nth-child(3)').attr('selected', 'selected');
$('#ddlSkill').trigger('liszt:updated');
```

But above code is not working

Comment: "multiselect dropdownlist"?? for multi select you need to use ListBoxFor instead of DropDownListFor

Answer (score 0):

CHHTML:

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(
        model => model.SelectedSkills,
        new SelectList(
        Model.SkillList,
        "Value",
        "Text",
        Model.SelectedSkills
        ),
        new
        {
            @class = "chosen",
            id = "ddlSkill",
            name = "ddlPersonSkill",
            @tabindex = "4",
            multiple = "true"
        }
        )
```

Javascript to show all selected:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var conceptName = $('#ddlSkill').find(":selected").text();
        alert(conceptName);
    });
```

Model jsut for example:

```
public string[] SelectedSkills { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> SkillList { get; set; }

    public MyModel()
    {
        SkillList = new List<SelectListItem>();
        ((List<SelectListItem>)SkillList).Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Skill 1", Value = "1" });
        ((List<SelectListItem>)SkillList).Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Skill 2", Value = "2" });
        ((List<SelectListItem>)SkillList).Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Skill 3", Value = "3" });
        ((List<SelectListItem>)SkillList).Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Skill 4", Value = "4" });

        SelectedSkills = new string[3];
        SelectedSkills[0] = "1";
        SelectedSkills[1] = "2";
        SelectedSkills[2] = "3";
    }
```